# Import a csv file in python with row of different lenght

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, csv

i'm trying to import in python a file csv with tab (\t) as separator. Eventually i want to put the data in a numpy array.

The file is something like this

```
1 2 3 4 5 6
1 2 3 4
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

unfortunately i can't know the max length of the row beforehand.

Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Read the file line by line, split of the delimiter, and collect values in a list of lists.  There are ways of padding such a list to fill an array, but lets get that list first.

Comment: What have you tried yourself?

Answer (score 0):

As hpaulj said, read all lines and split each line by your separator.

Like this (simplefied)

```
with open("filename.txt", "r") as file:
    lines = file.readlines()

for line in lines:
    values = line.split(" ")
```